# Averaging subsets of images with imagemagick, iteratively

Tags: shell-script, graphics, imagemagick

I have a hundred images and I want to average them 5 at a time.

The imagemagick command for the first 5 is:

```
convert -background transparent %d.jpg[1-5] -average output1.jpg
```

The imagemagick command for the second 5 is:

```
convert -background transparent %d.jpg[2-6] -average output2.jpg
```

The imagemagick command for the third 5 is:

```
convert -background transparent %d.jpg[3-7] -average output3.jpg
```

How can I do this in Windows programmatically? In other words, can I write a batch file to run imagemagick to do this with a loop? Or is there a better language/method/alternative?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Super User!  Things work a bit differently here from how they are on traditional forums you might be used to. If your problem has been solved, you don't need to edit that into the title - just click the checkmark by the answer that solved your question, and it'll automatically accept that answer and mark your question as solved! You can learn more about how those types of things work here on the [about] page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be easy enough to do with a batch file like the following:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /l %%f in (1,1,5) do (
    set /a cnt=%%f+4

    REM If the output looks ok, remove the "echo" from the following line to actually run convert
    echo convert -background transparent %%d.jpg[%%f-!cnt!] -average output%%f.jpg
)
endlocal
```

Here's the output with the "echo" in place:

```
convert -background transparent %d.jpg[1-5] -average output1.jpg
convert -background transparent %d.jpg[2-6] -average output2.jpg
convert -background transparent %d.jpg[3-7] -average output3.jpg
convert -background transparent %d.jpg[4-8] -average output4.jpg
convert -background transparent %d.jpg[5-9] -average output5.jpg
```

Tip: Be sure to specify the full path to imagemagick's convert.exe, otherwise Windows' own *convert* command (converts a FAT volume to NTFS) is likely to run by default.

Comment: Hey Karan - good answer, but would you mind adding an little extra info about what the batch file is actually doing? Delayed expansion is confusing (even as someone who's used it before), and it would be great to have some explanation of what the logical flow of the program is.

Comment: Umm, I'm not even sure what sort of explanation about the flow I should include! %%f gets values from 1-5 in the for loop, and cnt gets %%f's *current* value + 4 (so you get 1-5, 2-6 etc. in the output). As for delayed expansion, hoo boy that's a whole can of worms. :) I'd highly encourage anyone interested to check out http://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html and http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html for more (to my surprise the latter page coincidentally has a *very* similar example to the loop I used above!)

Comment: That's basically what I was looking for - just a description of which loop does what.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that I cobbled together that works as a Windows batch file for thousands of images:

> 1. rem we will combine 5 images
> 2. set /a U=0
> 3. set /a V=1
> 4. set /a W=2
> 5. set /a X=3
> 6. set /a Y=4
> 7. rem we will only look at the first 15 images
> 8. set /a terminator=15
> 9. :loop
> 10. set /a W= %W% + 1
> 11. set /a V= %V% + 1
> 12. set /a U= %U% + 1
> 13. set /a X= %X% + 1
> 14. set /a Y= %Y% + 1
> 15. if %Y%==%terminator% goto close
> 16. goto open
> 17. :close
> 18. pause
> 19. exit
> 20. :open
> 21. convert %%d.jpg[%U%-%Y%] -average -auto-level %U%out.jpg
> 22. goto loop

There is some funny business using a `for next` loop where one needs to remember to set delayed local expression and to use the bang (`!`) character around the variable name instead of percent signs. I learned that independently before I came back here and saw that you had solved my question. A simple goto with a loop is more transparent, although the for statement is more elegant.

Comment: I tried to upvote Karan's solution but i dont have enough reputation :(

Comment: Accepting Karan's answer will give him reputation points for the answer, and mark your question as solved. You also get +2 reputation for yourself, just for accepting an answer on a question. I edited the formatting in your answer here; check out the [formatting reference](http://superuser.com/editing-help) for more info.